# Apache NIFI: ExtractAvroMetadata process

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

The `extractAvroMetadata` indicates in its properties section that for the propoerty `'Metadata Keys'` we  can use a comma-seperated list to indicate the fields to get for the avro schema.

Has anyone already used that option since when I mention a list like `doc,namesapce` it does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says this:

"A comma-separated list of keys indicating key/value pairs to extract from the Avro file header. The key 'avro.schema' can be used to extract the full schema in JSON format, and 'avro.codec' can be used to extract the codec name if one exists."

So you can only use keys that are in the header, or the two mentioned keys.

Comment: Hello, Bryan , thanks for your respone , it was exactmy what i done , i mentioned the below value: namespace, doc which does exist in the header however i got nothing in the attributes of the output flowfile.